# Cannot modify network stuck on peering

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, google-vpc

> Failed to update peering first-vpc-my-project-second-vpc: There is a peering operation in progress on the local or peer network. Try again later.

This is the error that has been plaguing me for the last few days.

Whenever I try any change on the VPC I get hit with that error.

Create a Route? Fails with that error. Create a new peer? Fails with that error. Delete a VPC? Suprise, same error

I traced the error to a peer connection waiting for a connection on the other project. But guess what happens if I go there and try to create it manually?

I have followed the advice in the error message and waited for 48 hours, and it still appears.

I have tried deleting the problematic peer, deleting the network, saying my hail Marys (creating a new project is not an option). Yet nothing works.

How can I get for the network be unstuck creating a peer connection that never ends?

Answer (score 1):

If your resources are in the `europe-west9-a` region, you may be impacted by this ongoing [issue](https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/dS9ps52MUnxQfyDGPfkY). Google appears to be working on addressing this problem since its made its way to their [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/summary). I'd suggest that you monitor the status of the issue through the [dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/summary). You may also try deploying your resources on a different region/zone.

Comment: After a quick chat with support it was solved. It was because of the outage in Google Cloud Console.